# How do I replace_na over multiple lists

Tags: r

I need to replace NA with FALSE across multiple lists. I can do it in the most basic way. Here is what I have so far -

```
mydataframe$POBA<-replace_na(mydataframe$POBA,FALSE)
mydataframe$POBA2<-replace_na(mydataframe$POBA2,FALSE)
mydataframe$POBA3<-replace_na(mydataframe$POBA3,FALSE)
```

Is there a way to combine all three to reduce the code? Using a For Loop or referring to a range of columns?

Just started teaching myself R and I've tried multiple variations, but none that seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
mydataframe <- mydataframe %>%
                mutate_at(vars(starts_with("POBA)), replace_na, FALSE)
```

In the devel version of `dplyr`,  `across` can be used in `mutate`

```
mydataframe %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with("POBA"), replace_na, FALSE))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it assuming lists with a variety of names (i.e. not just starting with POBA)?

Comment: @Chris2015  You can add the  columns of interest  in vars i.e. `vars(POBA1, POBA2, ...)` or as a range (`vars(POBA1:POBA10)`) or as index

Answer (score 0):

You could use the apply family for that

```
lapply(mydataframe, replace_na, FALSE)
```

Note: This would alter all columns and will return a list object. This can easily be converted to a data.frame again with `as.data.frame()` if you need that.

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(POBA = c(TRUE,TRUE,NA), 
                          POBA2 = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE), 
                          POBA3 = c(NA, TRUE, TRUE))
lapply(mydataframe, tidyr::replace_na, FALSE)
# $POBA
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 
# $POBA2
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 
# $POBA3
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I tried lapply(mydataframe,replace_na,FALSE) but this did not work for some reason.